# Missing Event actions and Procedures in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, runtime, firemonkey

I have a program in Delphi to drag and drop a image component from one panel to another panel but here I am using "TWincontrol" and "OnStartDrag" event for each image component and it works good, Sample code given bellow.
When I implement the same in Firemonkey i found that those events and procedures are missing. So is there any way or replacement for the above mentioned events and procedure?

I would like to know can we drag the component when the "dragmode" property is set to "dmManual" and is there any way to change the property at run time by using some code?

Sample Code:

```
TMyDragObject = class(TDragControlObject)    
protected    
function GetDragImages: TDragImageList; override;    
end;    

procedure TForm1.Shape1StartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);    
var    
b:TBitmap;    
index:integer;    
p:TPoint;    
begin    
if Sender is TImage then    
with Sender as TImage do    
begin    
p:=screentoclient(mouse.cursorpos);    
MouseX:=p.x;    
MouseY:=p.y;    
DragObject := TMyDragObject.Create(TImage(Sender));     
end;    
end;    

procedure TForm1.Panel1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);    
var    
shape:TImage;    
begin    
if source is tMyDragObject then    
with source as TMyDragObject do    
begin    
shape:=TImage(control);    
shape.parent:=TWincontrol(sender);    
shape.left:=x-MouseX;    
shape.top:=y-MouseY;    
end;    
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the property `DragMode` to `dmAutomatic` to allow the drag...
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TControl.DragMode

The example below shows you how to move a shape inside/from-to panels... so, it works with FireMonkey...

If you right click, you change the color of the shape.. red, drag forbidden... otherwise, authorized...

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    RoundRect1: TRoundRect;
    procedure PanelDragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject; const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure PanelDragDrop(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject; const Point: TPointF);
    procedure RoundRect1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.PanelDragDrop(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject; const Point: TPointF);
begin
  if ((data.Source <> nil) and (data.Source is TRoundRect) and (Sender is TPanel)) then
  begin
    with TRoundRect(data.Source) do
    begin
      Parent := TPanel(Sender);
      Position.X := Point.X - (Width  / 2);  // Mouse cursor is center on the dragged object
      Position.Y := Point.Y - (Height / 2);
      DragMode   := TDragMode.dmManual;      // Disable drag by default (authorized later if not red)
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PanelDragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject; const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := Data.Source is TRoundRect;       // Can be moved on the same panel... update if you don't want
end;

procedure TForm1.RoundRect1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if Sender is TRoundRect then
  begin
    with TRoundRect(Sender) do
    begin
      if Button = TMouseButton.mbRight then
      begin
        if Fill.Color <> claRed then
        begin
          Fill.Color := claRed;
        end
        else
        begin
          Fill.Color := claBlue;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        if Fill.Color <> claRed then
        begin
          DragMode := TDragMode.dmAutomatic;   // can be dragged
        end
        else
        begin
          DragMode := TDragMode.dmManual;      // drag forbidden
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**The FMX** (2 TPanel ; 1 TRoundRect):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Drag...'
  ClientHeight = 418
  ClientWidth = 820
  Visible = False
  StyleLookup = 'backgroundstyle'
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Position.Point = '(8,8)'
    Width = 433.000000000000000000
    Height = 401.000000000000000000
    OnDragOver = PanelDragOver
    OnDragDrop = PanelDragDrop
    TabOrder = 1
    object RoundRect1: TRoundRect
      Position.Point = '(48,40)'
      Width = 129.000000000000000000
      Height = 81.000000000000000000
      OnMouseDown = RoundRect1MouseDown
      Fill.Color = claBlue
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Position.Point = '(448,8)'
    Width = 361.000000000000000000
    Height = 401.000000000000000000
    OnDragOver = PanelDragOver
    OnDragDrop = PanelDragDrop
    TabOrder = 2
  end
end
```

Of course, it works also with TImage...
[image: Step 1] [image: Step 2] [image: Step 3] [image: Step 4]